I am trying to get Visual Studio Code to handle a solution file
I think this is pretty straightforward and is a problem or issue that others have faced and solved. I imagine that this must be a common thing.
I am trying to get Visual Studio Code to work with a C# program. So, I asked chatgpt and I got this result that I made a screen capture of.  If you want, you can see it here.  https://likablelogic.org/images/chatgpt.png.
The instruction I received involved using the Visual Studio Code IDE to first install the proper extensions and then perform command line entries through the Terminal in the Visual Studio IDE.
The extensions I installed are the Microsoft C# Dev Kit and the C# extension.

The chatgpt instruction includes the step of installing the extension vscode-solution-explorer.

But I am not really able to open the solution, .SLN, file in a Solution Explorer window like I could do with Visual Studio 2022 and then use the IDE to step through the code and debug it. I am able to run old projects that I had developed and debugged in Visual Studio 2022. But in Visual Studio Code, I am not yet able to step through the source code and put breakpoints in order to do actual development.
I am able to build the solution by using the following command:
dotnet build MySAolution.sln

and I am able to run the project by using the following command:
dotnet run —project MyProject/MyProject.csproj

But I do not know how to use the Solution Explorer and any menu commands to debug my code and step through the C# code.
Please help.

There are Solution Explorer and Run and Debug from the official document, and there is a step by step tutorial by Microsoft.

The following may be of interest: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/whyvscode (scroll to the bottom for the URLs).

Step 1 is don't use generative AI for answering factual questions. They are designed to create collections of words that look right for creative/artistic purposes, not serve as actual "intelligent" systems, let alone authoritative ones.
